# UITextField calls textFieldDidEndEditing when cleared but `text` property has data

Tags: ios, ios6, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

Did anyone notice that `UITextField` calls `textFieldDidEndEditing` after clear button is pressed but `text` property still has old data ?

I'm not sure what code-sample I can provide here. I'm using storyboard if that matters.

For now I have to rely on taking data from all edit controls on main form's "Submit" button. But ideally I'd prefer to collect data in `textFieldDidEndEditing` handler.

Are there any better workarounds ?

I'm on iOS 6.

**Update**: Basically here is what I have on the form

- `UITextField` and `UiButton` are on the form.
- Keyboard dimissed by calling `resignFirstResponder` in handler of `UITapGestureRecognizer`

Steps to reproduce the issue:

- Click on edit control. Enter some text.
- Tap outside of text control.
- `textFieldDidEndEditing` is called. Property `.text` has value I entered. All good.
- Click on edit control again.
- Click on clear button.
- `textFieldDidEndEditing` is called again. But property `.text` still has value I just deleted !
- Now as you see cursor blinking inside UITextField tap on Button on the form.
- Keyboard is dismissed by `textFieldDidEndEditing` was never called.

I'll upload sample project on GitHub tomorrow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the exact same problem.  In my case, at least, it was due to having added a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to `self.view` (to allow for dismissing the keyboard if tapping outside of a `UITextField`) **and setting `cancelsTouchesInView=NO` on the gesture recognizer**.  I had set that property in order to get hyperlinking working on a `TTTAttributesLabel` I have elsewhere in the View.

My workaround was to watch for keyboard show and hide notifications, and toggle that property accordingly:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShowNotification:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHideNotification:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
```

(sign up for notifications)

```
- (void)keyboardDidShowNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
}

- (void)keyboardDidHideNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
}
```

(handle notifications)

The only problem, behavior-wise, is that the hyperlink still doesn't work when the keyboard is displayed: touching it will simply dismiss the keyboard, not forward the touch to the link handler.  But I can live with that.  After the keyboard is dismissed, the link works fine.

Answer (score 2):

First check `UITextFieldDelegate` is assigned or not, then

implement the `textFieldShouldClear` delegate and write the code here clear your textField

To do this you have to set the `clearButtonMode` property,

```
yourTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
yourTextField.delegate = self;
```

Then implement the `textFieldShouldClear` delegate

**.h file**

```
@interface myViewController: UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>{
}
```

**.m file**

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField

    yourTextFeild.text = @"";
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've done all that. Unfortunatelly it doesn't make a difference. Also I should mention that `textFieldDidEndEditing` is called **before** `textFieldShouldClear`.

Answer (score -1):

try here:

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*) textField
```